# Flutter Firestore startAt() endtAt() not working when orderby string values

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I Am trying to use startAt([1]) and endAt([3]) when order by title but it doesn't work.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('items')
  .orderBy("title", descending: false).startAt([1]).endAt([2]).limit(2).getDocuments();
```

When I try by order by rank startAt([1]) and endAt([3]) it works.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot5 = await Firestore.instance.collection('items')
  .orderBy("rank", descending: false).startAt([1]).endAt([2]).limit(2).getDocuments();
```

Works when i don't use endAt()

Why doesn't it work when i order by title?

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('items')
  .orderBy("title", descending: false).startAt([1]).limit(2).getDocuments();
```

Anyone have any idea?

What i have tried:
1. ensure packages are up to date
2. created indexes on firestore

[THIS DOES NOT WORK]
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('items').orderBy("title", descending: false).startAt([1]).endAt([2]).limit(2).getDocuments();

```
[THIS WORKS]
QuerySnapshot snapshot5 = await Firestore.instance.collection('items')
  .orderBy("rank", descending: false).startAt([1]).endAt([2]).limit(2).getDocuments();

[THIS WORKS]
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('items')
  .orderBy("title", descending: false).startAt([1]).limit(2).getDocuments();
```

What i expected was to be able to use endAt() when filtering but its throwing error

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that your `rank` fields are numeric, and your `title` field is a string. In that case this is expected behavior.

Firestore queries filter by **value** and not by offset. So when you:

```
.orderBy("rank", descending: false).startAt(1).endAt(2)
```

The documents are ordered by their rank, and then documents with a rank between 1 and 2 (inclusive) are returned.

When you do:

```
.orderBy("title", descending: false).startAt(1).endAt(2)
```

The documents are ordered by their title, and then documents with a title between 1 and 2 are returned. But since the titles are strings and not numbers, this means that no document matches the condition and nothing is returned.

Firestore does not have the concept of offset queries, where you tell it to skip the first `n` results.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was trying to do pagination with this. Looks like i am getting no where with the above code since it dosent work that way. any idea how i should do pagination ?

Comment: Since queries on Firebase don't work with offsets, you will have to track the pertinent field and the key of the last item you've shown. Search around for previous [questions about pagination on Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pagination) or [pagination on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+pagination) for more folks that have tried. Also note that there's a [paging adapter for Firestore in FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorepagingadapter).

Comment: BTW It takes parameter like `List<Object?>`. `Query<Map<String, dynamic>> startAt(List<Object?> values)
package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart`

Takes a list of [values], creates and returns a new [Query] that starts at the provided fields relative to the order of the query.

The [values] must be in order of [orderBy] filters.

Calling this method will replace any existing cursor "start" query modifiers.